# Не открывается *.edmx диаграмма

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net

Вместо диаграммы открывается XML.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Раньше все прекрасно работало.

VS 2015

Comment: Правая кнопка мыши → открыть с помощью? Visual Studio запоминает последний обработчик для типа файлов, кажется.

Comment: Пробовал, у меня там нет ADO Entity...

Comment: А, ну так в этом и дело. Может, у вас не установлен EF?

Comment: Был установлен, но пропал. В принципе, я проблему решил переустановкой VS.